# How does java do modulus calculations with negative numbers?

Tags: java, math, modulo, negative-number

Am I doing modulus wrong? Because in Java `-13 % 64` evaluates to `-13` but I want to get `51`.

Comment: Is this a math question, or a programming question? If it's a programming question, you should share code.

Comment: @Dan Even without a static main void ... I see code.

Comment: I get -13 & 64 == -13

Comment: *How* is it you are getting 51 ratehr than -13.

Comment: You aren't doing modulus at all. There is no modulo operator in Java. `%` is a remainder operator.

Comment: remainder is never negative, basic math concept. you will have to subastratct denom from output

Comment: I don't know how you're getting a positive number. Given the expression `x % y`, A) if `x` is negative the remainder is negative, ie `x % y == -(-x % y)`. B) the sign of `y` has no effect ie `x % y == x % -y`

Comment: Confusing question: Java 8 gives -13, as some other people say. Which Java version did you supposedly get that with?

Comment: Related: [Best way to make Java's modulus behave like it should with negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412179/best-way-to-make-javas-modulus-behave-like-it-should-with-negative-numbers)

Comment: I've checked the original question wording, where the author said "I keep getting -13 % 64 = -13 not -13 % 64 = 51" which is the opposite of what this question became after series of edits. So I've restored the original meaning.

Comment: Same thing, but for JavaScript: [JavaScript % (modulo) gives a negative result for negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4467539/4561887)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Both definitions of modulus of negative numbers are in use - some languages use one definition and some the other.

If you want to get a negative number for negative inputs then you can use this:

```
int r = x % n;
if (r > 0 && x < 0)
{
    r -= n;
}
```

Likewise if you were using a language that returns a negative number on a negative input and you would prefer positive:

```
int r = x % n;
if (r < 0)
{
    r += n;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work good if n is negative. If you user same example from Java 7 Lang Spec (Section 15.17.3): (-5) % (-3) = -2. Adding -3 will not work. You should add absolute value of n if you want to be sure that value is positive.

Comment: In Java negative modulo does not change anything, if you use an Abs() anyway, just write r = x % abs(n). I don't like if statement, I'd rather write r = ((x%n) + n) % n. Concerning power of 2 modulo (2,4,8,16,etc..) and positive answer, consider binary mask r = x & 63.

Comment: In the context of Java (as per question tag) this answer is essentially "wrong". Given the expression `x % y`, A) if `x` is negative the remainder is negative, ie `x % y == -(-x % y)`. B) the sign of `y` has no effect ie `x % y == x % -y`

Comment: Without opening a new question, and for people landing on this page while Googling for C and C++ `%` (myself included), I'd like to point out that [the same rules also apply to C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73782011/4561887).

Answer (score 78):

Since "mathematically" both are correct:

```
-13 % 64 = -13 (on modulus 64)  
-13 % 64 = 51 (on modulus 64)
```

One of the options had to be chosen by Java language developers and they chose:

> the sign of the result equals the sign of the dividend.

Says it in Java specs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3

Comment: The question is "why does Java give me `-13 % 64 = 51` when I was expecting `-13`?".

Comment: @pascal: java gives you the right definition in math and  the way it has been implemented to do that not the thing you expecting from it.

Comment: The mathematically sane behavior is available in Java 8: [Math.floorMod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-)

Comment: Something in their [15.17.3. Remainder Operator %](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) examples isn't clear. `int result = (-5) % 3;` gives -2. `int result = (-3) % 5;` gives -3. In general, `int result = (-a) % b;` gives the right answer when |-a| > b. In order to get the proper result when |-a| < b we should wrap the divisor. `int result = ((-a) % b) + b;` for negative a or `int result = (((-a) % b) + b) % b;` for positive or negative a

Comment: @Caner I didn't understand this, How could both be same?

Answer (score 22):

Are you sure you are working in Java? 'cause Java gives -13 % 64 = -13 as expected. The sign of dividend!

Answer (score 14):

**Note that this answer was for a previous, different version of the question.**

Your result is wrong for Java.
Please provide some context how you arrived at it (your program, implementation and version of Java).

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)

> 15.17.3 Remainder Operator %
>
> [...]
>
> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a.

> 15.17.2 Division Operator /
> [...]
> Integer division rounds toward 0.

Since / is rounded towards zero (resulting in zero), the result of % should be negative in this case.

Comment: Something in their [15.17.3. Remainder Operator %](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) examples isn't clear.
`int result = (-5) % 3;` gives -2
`int result = (-3) % 5;` gives -3
In general, `int result = (-a) % b;` gives the right answer when |-a| > b
In order to get the proper result when |-a| < b we should wrap the divisor.
`int result = ((-a) % b) + b;` for negative a or `int result = (((-a) % b) + b) % b;` for positive or negative a.

Comment: Your comment is quite unclear. The section *defines* the correct result, and the examples agree with that definition. For your example `(-3) % 5` the correct result according to the definition is `-3`, and a correct implementation of Java should produce that result.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself correctly. What I meant by "the right answer" when |-a|<b is that in order to get a positive result we should "wrap" the given result from a%b by adding b to it. In my example, `(-3)%5` indeed gives `-3`, and if we want the positive remainder we should add 5 to it, and then the result will be `2`

Answer (score 6):

you can use

```
(x % n) - (x < 0 ? n : 0);
```

Comment: @ruslik You can also do: `((x % k) + k) % k`. (Though yours is probably more readable.)

Comment: @JohnKurlak You version works like this:
4 % 3 = 1 OR 4 % -3 = -2 OR -4 % 3 = 2 OR -4 % -3 = -1
but the one from ruslik works like this:
4 % 3 = 1 OR 4 % -3 = 1 OR -4 % 3 = -4 OR -4 % -3 = 2

Comment: @Joschua Thanks for pointing this out.  My code is helpful for when you want the modulus result to be in the range of `[0, sign(divisor) * divisor)` instead of `[0, sign(dividend) * divisor)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is in wikipedia:
[modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

It says, that in Java the sign on modulo operation is the same as that of dividend. and since we're talking about the rest of the division operation is just fine, that it returns -13 in your case, since -13/64 = 0. -13-0 = -13.

EDIT: Sorry, misunderstood your question...You're right, java should give -13. Can you provide more surrounding code?

Answer (score 2):

Modulo arithmetic with negative operands is defined by the language designer, who might leave it to the language implementation, who might defer the definition to the CPU architecture.

<s>I wasn't able to find a Java language definition.</s>
 Thanks Ishtar, Java Language Specification for the [Remainder Operator %](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.3) says that the sign of the result is the same as the sign of the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

`x = x + m = x - m` in modulus `m`.
so `-13 = -13 + 64` in modulus `64`  and `-13 = 51` in modulus `64`.
assume `Z = X * d + r`, if `0 < r < X` then in division `Z/X` we call `r` the remainder.
`Z % X` returns the remainder of `Z/X`.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this, you could add `64` (or whatever your modulus base is) to the negative value until it is positive

```
int k = -13;
int modbase = 64;

while (k < 0) {
    k += modbase;
}

int result = k % modbase;
```

The result will still be in the same equivalence class.

Answer (score 1):

The mod function is defined as the amount by which a number exceeds the largest integer multiple of the divisor that is not greater than that number. So in your case of

```
-13 % 64
```

the largest integer multiple of 64 that does not exceed -13 is -64. Now, when you subtract -13 from -64 it equals 51 `-13 - (-64) = -13 + 64 = 51`

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Java  JDK 1.8.0_05  -13%64=-13

you could try  -13-(int(-13/64))
in other words  do division cast to an integer to get rid of the fraction part
then subtract from numerator
So numerator-(int(numerator/denominator))   should give the correct remainder & sign

Answer (score 0):

In Java latest versions you get `-13%64 = -13`. The answer will always have sign of numerator.

Comment: In which version was this change made?

Comment: In java 7 it clearly mentions that mod will have sign of numerator :)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen It was never changed.

Answer (score 0):

According to section 15.17.3 of the JLS, "The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary numeric promotion produces a result value such that (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a.
This identity holds even in the special case that the dividend is the negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its type and the divisor is -1 (the remainder is 0)."

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

### How to get only positive modulus numbers in C or C++ (since the `%` operator allows negative numbers)

Java and C and C++ all appear to act similarly in this manner. Without opening a new question, I'd like to present the approach for C and C++ as well.

From [modulus_of_positive_and_negative_integers.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/modulus_of_positive_and_negative_integers.c) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```c
/// A function to perform and return the mathematical modulus as returned by
/// programming calculators and Google. In other words, it will **always**
/// return a positive value, unlike the `%` remainder operator in C!
/// Example:
/// So, `-5 % 180` in C or C++ is `-5`, but `mathematical_modulo(-5, 180)`
/// is the same as "-5 mod 180" in a calculator or on Google, and is `175`.
int mathematical_modulo(int num1, int num2)
{
    int mod = num1 % num2;
    if (mod < 0)
    {
        mod += num2;
    }

    return mod;
}
```

#### Sample tests of the code above:

Notice that `-10 % 180` produces `-10` in C and C++ since the `%` operator acts like a simple remainder, not a roll-over modulo, whereas `mathematical_modulo(-10, 180)` produces `170`, since the underflow wraps back around to the max value of 180 in this case, and then down 10 steps again.

```c
printf("-10 %% 180 = %4i\n", -10 % 180);
printf("  0 %% 180 = %4i\n",   0 % 180);
printf(" 10 %% 180 = %4i\n",  10 % 180);
printf("\n");

printf("mathematical_modulo(-10, 180) = %4i\n",
        mathematical_modulo(-10, 180));
printf("mathematical_modulo(  0, 180) = %4i\n",
        mathematical_modulo(  0, 180));
printf("mathematical_modulo( 10, 180) = %4i\n",
        mathematical_modulo( 10, 180));
printf("\n");
```

Sample output:

```
-10 % 180 =  -10
  0 % 180 =    0
 10 % 180 =   10

mathematical_modulo(-10, 180) =  170
mathematical_modulo(  0, 180) =    0
mathematical_modulo( 10, 180) =   10
```

#### Calculator tool on Linux

In C or C++, `-10 % 180` is `-10`. But, on my Linux calculator, `-10 mod 180` is `170`:

[image]

#### Google calculator in browser

On Google, [`-10 % 180`](https://www.google.com/search?q=-10+%25+180&oq=-10+%25+180&aqs=chrome..69i57.1366j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), *or* [`-10 mod 180`](https://www.google.com/search?q=-10+mod+180&sxsrf=ALiCzsbGMTLP7UIf0g7GTFZwbf-RrnNWvA%3A1663652436218&ei=VFIpY9aFDevekPIPyrm3uAo&ved=0ahUKEwjW__Wj1KL6AhVrL0QIHcrcDacQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=-10+mod+180&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQyAZYkwpg0gtoAXAAeACAAW-IAZQDkgEDMy4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) (same thing on Google) are both `170` as well:

[image]

### References

1. My own experimentation, learning, and self-study via my code linked-to above.
2. [JavaScript `%` (modulo) gives a negative result for negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4467539/4561887)
3. This answer: [How does java do modulus calculations with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403570/4561887)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Java returns 51 in this case. I am running Java 8 on a Mac and I get:

```
-13 % 64 = -13
```

Program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = -13;
        int j = 64;
        System.out.println(i % j);
    }
}
```

Comment: @XaverKapeller, no ! Many people pointed out that mathematically speaking -13 and 51 are correct. In Java, -13 is the expected answer, and it's what I got too, so I don't know how submitter got 51, it's mystery. Mode details about the context could help to answer correctly this question.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller: How can 51 and -13 both can be correct ? Java would return just one value ..

Comment: @XaverKapeller How can an answer that documents what Java actually does possibly be wrong?

Comment: @EJP I think 3 years ago when I wrote this I was dumb enough to value mathematical accuracy more than the simple reality of how java deals with this. Thanks for reminding me to remove my stupid comment :D