# How is -13 % 64 = -13 in PHP?

Tags: php, math, modulus

Derived from this question : (Java) [How does java do modulus calculations with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403542/how-is-13-64-51)

Anywhere to force PHP to return positive 51?

**update**
Looking for a configuration setting to fix, instead hard-guessing

Or other math function like bcmath?

**updated**
Not entire convinced by that java answer, as it does not take account of negative modulus
`-13+(-64) =?`

Comment: updated ... looking for solution without using hard-guessing method

Comment: There is no configuration setting to change how math works in PHP. If there was then it would probably break PHP, which I would imagine uses lots of calculations internally

Comment: That's not an intended algorithm. Surprisingly Python and Perl accept it, but PHP doesn't. Use a workaround. Btw, `fmod()` and `bcmod()` and `gmp_mod()` don't either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) is available, you can use [`gmp_mod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-mod.php)

> Calculates n modulo d. The result is always non-negative, the sign of d is ignored.

Example:

```
echo gmp_strval(gmp_mod('-13', '64')); // 51
```

Note that `n` and `d` have to be GMP number resources or numeric strings. Anything else won't work¹

```
echo gmp_strval(gmp_mod(-13, 64));
echo gmp_mod(-13, 64);
```

will both return -51 instead ([which is a bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52906)).

**¹** <sup>running the above in this [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gqN5aa), will produce 51 in all three cases. It won't do that on my development machine.</sup>

Comment: I really wouldn't use the GMP library for this.  It's far too heavyweight.  The answer below by Spiny Norman is much better.

Answer (score 17):

Anyway, the post you referenced already gave the correct answer:

```
$r = $x % $n;
if ($r < 0)
{
    $r += abs($n);
}
```

Where $x = -13 and $n = 64.

Comment: is there a configuration for modulus instead guess ourself?

Comment: There's no guessing involved, just calculating which (wow) you're already doing some of.

Comment: The `if` should preferrably be a `while`.

Comment: @mario It doesn't hurt to use `while`, but due to the nature of modulus, $r will never be < -63 (that is, -($n-1)).

Comment: The while is not necessary, but adding the absolute value of n to r rather than just n would also solve the case where n is negative.

Answer (score 4):

The modulo operation should find the remainder of division of a number by another. But strictly speaking **in most mainstream programming languages the modulo operation malfunctions if dividend or/and divisor are negative**. This includes [PHP, Perl, Python, Java, C, C++, etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation)

Why I say malfunction? Because according to mathematic definition, **[a remainder must be zero or positive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#The_case_of_general_integers)**.

The simple solution is to handle the case yourself:

```
if r < 0  then r = r + |divisor|;
```

|divisor| is the absolute value of divisor.

Another solution is to use a library (as @Gordon pointed). However I wouldn't use a library to handle a simple case like this.

Answer (score 2):

I hate using `if` in this case when you can calculate it right away.

```
$r = ($x % $n + $n) % $n;
```

when `$n` is positive.

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) says that

> The result of the modulus operator % has the same sign as the dividend — that is, the result of $a % $b will have the same sign as $a. For example

so this is not configurable. Use the options suggested in the question you linked to