# Increment character in php

Tags: php

Incrementing a character in php relative to its alphabetic position works as per:

```
$a = 'a'; 
++$a;
echo $a;
```

The output is 'b'

However, is it possible to increment the position by multiples i.e. 10 for example.

```
$a = 'a'; 
$a += 2;
echo $a;
```

This outputs an integer not 'c'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert the character into its ASCII value using ord(), increment/decrement that value then convert it back to a character using chr():

```
$a = 'a';
$num = 2;
$a = chr(ord($a)+$num);
echo $a;
// outputs c
```

[ord](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)- Return ASCII value of character
[chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)- Return a specific character

If you want the increment/decrement to wrap around a value that exceeds `z` then you can use this:

```
$a = 'a';
$num = 28;
echo chr((26 + (ord($a)+$num-97)) % 26 + 97);
// outputs c
```

**Note:** As php modulus of a negative number returns a negative number this will not work or `$num` values < -26 alternative solution include using [`gmp_mod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-mod.php) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409281/how-is-13-64-13-in-php).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

i think you can increment value like this.

```
 $a = a;
  for ($n = 0; $n <= 10; $n++) {
    echo '<p>'.$a.'</p>';
    $a++;
  }
```

It outputs this

```
a

b

c

d

e

f

g

h

i

j

k
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think php can do that, that way. You could do this:

```
$num = 10;
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
  ++$a;
}
```