# How could I have the index of an array 'roll over' when incrementing?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

So I have an Array with a length of 4. When I increment it by 1 and the number gets bigger than the length of the array, I'd like it to rollover.

For example:

```
current_index = 3;
current_index++;
//current_index is now 0 again

current_index = 3;
current_index += 2;
//current_index would be 1

current_index = 0;
current_index--;
//current_index would be 3
```

I'm currently solving it with if-else like this

```
if (current_index == textviewlist.length + 1)
     current_index = 0;
else if (current_index == textviewlist.length + 2)
     current_index = 1;
else if (current_index == -1)
     current_index = 3;
```

But I feel like this isn't an appropriate solution, or "good" code.

**Edit**: I tried your suggestion, but apparently java behaves strangely with negative numbers.
When I try

```
current_index = (current_index - 1) % textviewlist.length;
```

Java takes the index "0", decreases it by 1 ("-1") and then

```
 -1 % 4 = -1
```

I expected it to be 3, see [Wolfram Alpha: -1 mod 4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%20mod%204&a=*MC.!-1%20mod%204-_*Math-) 
But apparently the java % operator is not the same as the modulo operator?

**Edit 2**: I found a solution here: [Best way to make Java's modulus behave like it should with negative numbers? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412179/best-way-to-make-javas-modulus-behave-like-it-should-with-negative-numbers/4412200#4412200)

I can just do:

```
current_index -= 1;
current_index = (current_index % textviewlist.length + textviewlist.length)  % textviewlist.length;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator.

```
current_index = (current_index + n) % 4;
```

Comment: Because google ranks this page highest when searching for the same thing but in JavaScript here is the JS version: `current_index = (current_index + n + 4) % 4;`

Comment: The comment above is #fakenews

Answer (score 5):

Divide the incremented index modulo the array's length:

```
current_index = (current_index + n) % textviewlist.length
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use mod as follows:

```
current_index = (current_index + i) % 4.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Just set it to itself modulo 4 - or rather, the length of the list - after each increment.

```
current_index += 2;
current_index %= textviewlist.length;
```

or combined:

```
current_index = (current_index + 2) % textviewlist.length;
```

You could also do this:

```
current_index += n;
while (current_index >= textviewlist.length) {
    current_index -= textviewlist.length;
}
```

although I'd be surprised if that isn't slower than the modulo operation, especially since your list length is a power of 2.

Either way, it might be a good idea to encapsulate all this into an `increment()` function:

```
int increment(int old_index, int n) {
    return (old_index + n) % textviewlist.length;
}
```

**EDIT:** ah, I didn't realize you were working in Java. (I think C's modulo operator mimics the mathematical definition on negative numbers) A slight improvement on the solution you found would be

```
int increment(int old_index, int n) {
    return (old_index + n + textviewlist.length) % textviewlist.length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really like the idea of an `increment()` function. However, what happens with negative values? I just edited my question to reflect that.