# java array traversal in circular manner

Tags: java, arrays, traversal

I have an array which have 1 2 3 4 5 values.

```
array a = [ 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now i want to traverse it in circular manner.
like i want to print 2 3 4 5 1 or 3 4 5 1 2 or 5 1 2 3 4 and so on.
any **algorithm** on this?

**Edit:** I want to print all the combination in circular manner. i don't want to state starting point at its initial phase.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
int start = ...
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[(start + i) % a.length]);
}
```

<sup>(If you want to iterate the array backwards from `start`, change `start + i` to `start - i + a.length` in the array subscript expression.  The `+ a.length` is needed because, in Java, `x % y` is negative when `x` is negative; see [Best way to make Java's modulus behave like it should with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412179))</sup>

I should note that this is probably not the most efficient way of expressing the loop ... in terms of execution speed.  However, the difference is small, and *most likely irrelevant*.

A more relevant point is whether using `%` in this way gives more readable code.  I think it does, but maybe that's because I've seen / used this particular idiom before.  Maybe a comment would be warranted.

Comment: This entire post really reminds me of that stupid fuzz buzz problem, lots of people answering with overly complicated non-sensical solutions, when there's an easier way to do things with no effort

Comment: I gave you a +1 for the three line solution that also deals with out out bounds cases :) However, I agree with your readability concern- I think the loop looks like it's a normal iteration at first glance which may not be ideal.

Comment: How do you invent something like that? How? :D

Comment: Don't ask me.  It isn't my invention.  Though I don't recall where I learned it.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
int start = // start position, must be in bounds
int i = start;
do {

   ....

   i++;
   if(i == a.length) i = 0;
} while(i != start);
```

Comment: what would be the value of start? i dont want to fix start value

Comment: Start is wherever you want to start the traversal in the array. To print 3 4 5 1 2, start should be 2, or to print 1 2 3 4 5 start should be 0 - maybe I've misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
int st = n ; // n is the starting position from where you print
for(int i = st; i < a.length; i++)
{
   -- print each array[i];
}

if(st != 0)
{
   for(int i = 0 ; i < st ; i++)
   {
      --- print each array[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to loop through the array, and change the current index if necessary (like move it to the start of the array when it meets the end)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    System.out.println(printCircularly(array, 4));
}

private static String printCircularly(int[] array, int startIndex) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int currentIndex = startIndex;
    do {
        sb.append(array[currentIndex++]);
        if (currentIndex > array.length - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    while (currentIndex != startIndex);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c)'s answer

```
int start = ...

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[(start - i + a.length) % a.length]);
}
```

Use this for reverse loop from start index. It's a little unclear, but in some cases very useful. For example: UI components like carousel.

And there's no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException!!!

Comment: you saved me big time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop with indexes, which is harder to read, you can use `Iterables` from `Google Guava` as follows :

```
List<Integer> myList = List.of(1,2,3);
Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = Iterables.cycle(myList).iterator();
```

then you will only have to use `myListIterator.next()`. example :

```
System.out.println(myListIterator.next());
System.out.println(myListIterator.next());
System.out.println(myListIterator.next());
System.out.println(myListIterator.next());
```

This will print :  1 2 3 1