# Relooping through array

Tags: java, arrays

So let's say I have an array of length 5 (let's just call it myArray[5]). If I add 4 to myArray[3], such like myArray[3+4], how can I make it loop through myArray again so that it becomes myArray[2]?

example)

```
myArray[3]

myArray[4]   //+1

myArray[0]   //+2

myArray[1]   //+3

myArray[2]   //+4
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the array length for a modulo operation:

```
int index = /* index you are using */;
myArray[index % myArray.length]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulus. `index % myArray.length` like

```
int[] myArray = new int[10];
for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
    System.out.println(i % myArray.length);
}
```

Output is 0 - 9 (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through the array in a circular fashion the modulus `%` operator is the way to go. If you combine that with the Java 8 streaming API:s the solution can look like this.

```
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Setup the array
    int startIndex = 3;              // Start index as per the OP's example
    int addIndex = 4;                // Add as per the OP's example

    // Loop via streams - no external looping
    IntStream.range(startIndex, startIndex + addIndex)
            .map(i -> myArray[i % myArray.length]) // circular loop
            .forEach(System.out::println /* Do your stuff */); // do your stuff
```

For more examples, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651965/java-array-traversal-in-circular-manner)