# Looking for a circular fixed size array-based deque

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for a `Deque` which has the following characteristics:

- it has fixed size
- if I add elements at the head/tail elements at the opposite end drop out
- it is array-based so I can access random elements in constant time
- I can add elements at the front or at the end (deque)

I checked the `Deque` implementations in the **JCF** but I did not find anything that fits.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html it exists, but it sounds like you'll have to make your own subclass to make it work in the fixed size

Comment: I know Deque exists in JCF I mentioned it in my question.

Comment: The closest is ArrayDeque. Why do you want to discard element? Why do you want random access in a queue esp as the random element might not be there any more?

Comment: I'm reading in lines from a very big file and I want to buffer them in  a collection so I can display it for the user. If the user scrolls down or up I want to read in the previous/next lines into this collection. I can't read in the whole file because it would lead to an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Are you willing to accept a home-grown type, as opposed to one already available in a public library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I love writing my own data types,

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Ring {

    private String[] data;
    int n = 0;

    public Ring(int size) {
        data = new String[size];
    }

    public void push(String s) {
        data[n] = s;
        n = (n + 1) % data.length;
    }

    public void shift(String s) {
        data[n = (n - 1) % data.length] = s;
    }

    public String get(int index) {
        return data[(n + index) % data.length];
    }

    public static class Examples {

        @Test
        public void shouldDropElementsWhenPushingTooFar() {
            Ring ring = new Ring(3);
            ring.push("A");
            ring.push("B");
            ring.push("C");
            ring.push("D");
            ring.push("E");
            assertEquals("C", ring.get(0));
            assertEquals("D", ring.get(1));
            assertEquals("E", ring.get(2));
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldAddElementsAtTheFront() {
            Ring ring = new Ring(3);
            ring.push("A");
            ring.push("B");
            ring.push("C");
            ring.push("D");
            ring.push("E");
            // rewind
            ring.shift("B");
            assertEquals("B", ring.get(0));
            assertEquals("C", ring.get(1));
            assertEquals("D", ring.get(2));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There is a bug in here: shifting will lead to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The fix is to change `(n - 1) % data.length` to `(n - 1 + data.length) % data.length`. Reason is that Java's modulo operator [can result in negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412179).

Comment: There is a bug in the code. Try below to run it.
  Ring ring = new Ring(4);
        ring.push("A");
        ring.push("B");
        System.out.println(ring.get(1));
       It return null, which is not expected output.