# Is this implementation of gcd correct

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

```
public static int divisor(int m, int n) {
    if (m == 0 || n == 0) {
        return m+n;
    } else {
        return divisor(n, m%n);
    }
}
```

It's giving me wrong answers for some input(I don't know which as they don't reveal which input they use for test case) in the amazon.interviewstreet.com

Also why this implementation keeps giving me stackoverflow(again no idea for which inputs)

```
public static int divisor(int m, int n) {
    if(m == 0 || n == 0) {
        return m+n;
    } else if (m > n) {
        return divisor(n, m%n);
    } else {
        return divisor(m, n%m);
    }
}
```

Please let me know what am I missing. I'm new to programming and am still a beginner.

Comment: _giving me wrong answers_ Then it is wrong.

Comment: ` return(m, n%m);` this even compile ?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typing mistake. I've edited the question. @SotiriosDelimanolis They don't give me explanation for wrong on which specific input so I'm asking that which possible input would produce wrong answers? Maybe that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first one is a code for a programming contest. If so be careful  with your data types. May be 'int' is not enough to hold the inputs. Try 'long' instead. 
(and this will work only if your algorithm is correct.)

Comment: Thanks got the answer. Had to use BigInteger instead of ints and long.

Comment: post the full code of your program. It will help to  understand whats going on.

Comment: This is the [link](http://pastebin.com/njdfF3Xf) to the code that ended in stackoverflow error previously.

Comment: @meteors I add the answer mistakenly to  the main question. check that.

Answer (score 1):

I think

`return(m, n%m);`

should be

`return divisor(m, n%m);`

Comment: I'm sorry that was just a typing mistake, Anyway I submitted with divisor(m, n%m); only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe invalid handling of negative values of `n` and `m`?
Read e.g. this: [Best way to make Java's modulus behave like it should with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412179/best-way-to-make-javas-modulus-behave-like-it-should-with-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

for the second part what is

return(m, n%m);

Is this code get compiled ?

use :

```
public static int divisor(int m, int n) {
if(m == 0 || n == 0)
    return m+n;
else if(m>n)
    return divisor(n, m%n);
else
    return divisor(m, n%m);}
```

Comment: I've changed the code but what input would cause the code to go into infinite loop(stackOverFlow)? I'm not able to get that.

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
return(m, n%m)
```

definitely does not compile, I suppose it was meant to be

```
return divisor(m, n%m);
```

Second, I guess what is wrong in the second snippet is handling of negative numbers. 
Because A and B have the same GCD as -A and -B, I would add

```
m = Math.abs(m);
n = Math.abs(n);
```

to the beginning of the method

Answer (score 1):

For the second part :

> Also why this implementation keeps giving me stackoverflow(again no idea for which inputs)?

Try this input set :

5
3 1 16 5 10

It will give you the stackoverflow error. For your given code in pastebin.

Why ?

If the input is '1' there will be this problem.

edit your code part like below and see the out put for input (1 1).

```
public static int divisor(int m, int n) {
    System.out.println("### "+m+" "+n);
    if (m == 0 || n == 0) {
        return m + n;
    } else if (m > n) {
        return divisor(n, m % n);
    } else {
        return divisor(m, n % m);
    }
}
```

in some point out put will be like this :

```
.
.
### 1 1134903170
### 1 0
### 1 1836311903
### 1 0
### 1 -1323752223
### -1323752223 1
### -1323752223 1
### -1323752223 1
.
.
```

because in your code the function calling is like below.

```
   public static int divFib(int num) {
    int i = 1, j = 2, temp;

    while (divisor(num, j) == 1) {
        temp = j;
        j = j + i;
        i = temp;
    }
    return j;
   }
```

divisor(num, j) will be called like divisor(1, 2) then below part will execute

```
else {
        return divisor(m, n % m);
    }
```

the calling will  be like divisor(1,0)  because n%m = 2%1 =0

then '1' will  be return as (m+n = 1).

then  while (divisor(num, j) == 1){} will  execute again and 'j' will be get increased. But 'num' is '1'. the same thing happens again and again. resulting 'j' to be a huge number and eventually it will assigned a negative number. (I think  you know why its happening).

The thing is this will not ever stopped. so the stack will be overflowed due to huge number of function calls.

I think this is a quite clear explanation and if you have any doubt please ask. 
(Sorry i mistakenly post the answer here.)

Comment: But that should be problem in the first implementation too then why it didn't give a stackoverflow error?

Comment: The reason is your first implementation the function calls will return a value after 2 call max. But in your second implementation it there will be huge number of non-returned function calls (which are still  in the stack until return a value from the successors ). And that is why your second cade is giving a stack overflow. your first code may give TLE or WA (in the programing contest manner)