# Using % operator in Java

Tags: java, operator-keyword, primitive

Why do I get 2 and not -2 in the following?

```
System.out.println(11%-3);
```

Considering that:

```
System.out.println(-11%3);
```

returns -2..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because % is the **remainder** after the two operands have been divided.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth since 11/-3 and -11/3 returns the same results, why do I get a different result using %

Comment: Because r = n - q*d, where n is numerator, d is denominator, q is quotient and r is remainder.

Comment: Because the remainder of the the numerator. If I divide `-3` into `11` the minus is somewhat irrelevant. Whereas if I divide `3` into `-11` then the remaining amount is from the `-11` and so is negative.

Comment: This answer has the logic(formula) behind it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412179/best-way-to-make-javas-modulus-behave-like-it-should-with-negative-numbers/4412200#4412200

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does java do modulus calculations with negative numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403542/how-does-java-do-modulus-calculations-with-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3):

> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary
>   numeric promotion ([§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) produces a result value such that
>   `(a/b)*b+(a%b)` is equal to `a`.

---

> It follows from this rule that the **result of the remainder operation
>   can be negative only if the dividend is negative**, and can be positive
>   only if the dividend is positive. Moreover, the magnitude of the
>   result is always less than the magnitude of the divisor.

(Emphasis mine.)

Additionally, refer to [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for information about modulo operators in various programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Rules are specified in [Jls 15.17.3 Remainder Operator %](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)   -

> It follows from this rule that
>   the result of the remainder operation can be negative only if the
>   dividend is negative, and can be positive only if the dividend is
>   positive. Moreover, the magnitude of the result is always less than
>   the magnitude of the divisor.

Answer (score 0):

Becaue the sign of the result equals the sign of the dividend.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.3

Answer (score 0):

First, "remainder()" means:
if
   a=b*c+r, a,b,c,r are integers.
Then
   a%b = c

But, how to choose c, different Programming Language has different implementation.

To C and Java, remainder was calculated as truncating:

-11 % 3 = 3*(-3)+(-2)
11 % (-3) = (-3)*(-3)+2

The key point is why choose -3? Because:

truncate(-11/3)=truncate(-3.66)=-3

"truncate()" get the int part close to 0

In other programming language，like Python, use floor division. Which means that in Python:
-11 % 3 = 3 * (floor(-11/3))+2

Please refer to: http://python-history.blogspot.sg/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Answer (score -3):

This is a math problem.

1st, -11%3 and 11%-3 are the same.

2nd, if you want a positive number, please remove 'minus'. try 11%3 or -11%-3