# Javascript modulo operator behaves differently from other languages

Tags: javascript, division, modulo

According to Wikipedia, the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (remainder of integer division) on `n` should yield a result between `0` and `n-1`.

This is indeed the case in `python`:

```
print(-1%5) # outputs 4
```

In `Ruby`:

```
puts -1%5 # outputs 4
```

In `Haskell`

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ mod (-1) 5
```

But in`Javascript`:

```
console.log(-1%5);
```

**The result is `-1` !!**

Why is that ? is there logic behind this design decision ?

While `-1` is equivalent to `4` modulo `5`, negative values makes it harder to use as indices.

For example:

```
arr[x%5]
```

would always be a valid expression in `python` and `Ruby` when the array length is more than `5`, but in the `Javascript`, this is an exception waiting to happen.

Comment: You reference Wikipedia and yet it clearly states `When either a or n is negative, the naive definition breaks down and programming languages differ in how these values are defined.` So it's not like progamming languages are in breach of it as you also claim.

Comment: It is evident that this is the case, the question is why ?

Comment: Also I don't see how `arr[x%5]` is `an exception waiting to happen` in JS - if you pass in a negative number you'll get a negative result, so you'll get `undefined`. If the operator did indeed work like python or whatever, then it will give you a _random_ element from the array. So you could have a bug and never find it until way later because it _seems_ like it works.

Comment: As for "why" that's the case - the dupe you were linked to last time did have the answer - `%` is treated as "give me the remainder". That seems to be the rationale.

Comment: The end result is that the `%n` function has `n` possible values when applied in other languages (e.g. `python`,`ruby`,`haskell`) but in `javascript` it has `2n-1` possible values

Comment: Did you actually read [the article you linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation), including the table about what the various programming languages do about negative operands?

Answer (score 2):

If by "modulus" you understand the remainder of the Euclidean division as common in mathematics, the [`%` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-applying-the-mod-operator) is not the modulo operator. It rather is called the *remainder operator*, whose result always has the same sign as the dividend. (In Haskell, the [`rem` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:rem) does this).

This behaviour is pretty common amongst programming languages, notably also in C and Java from which the arithmetic conventions of JavaScript were inspired.

Answer (score 1):

Note that while in most languages, ‘%’ is a remainder operator, in some (e.g. Python, Perl) it is a modulo operator. For two values of the same sign, the two are equivalent, but when the dividend and divisor are of different signs, they give different results. To obtain a modulo in JavaScript, in place of a % n, use `((a % n ) + n ) % n`

see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder