# is there a way to limit the .getId()

Tags: java, concurrency

```
Thread thbus = new Thread(bus);
bus.setName("Bus"+ thbus.getId());

Thread thmechanics = new Thread(bus);
bus.setMechanicsName("Mechanic "+ thmechanics.getId());

thbus.start();
```

These generate threads that are in my other classes. The `"Mechanic "+ thmechanics.getId()` line will print `"Mechanic"` + a random number. I want to know if there is a way to use the `.getId()` to print random number between (1-5).

Comment: *"Is there a way to get random number between (1-5)"* Did you try a web search? You'll find a gazillion answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy/pragmatically done, by using the `%` ([modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) operator:

```
(thread.getId() % 5 ) + 1
```

welcome ;)

Since [mod-in-java-produces-negative-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385024/mod-in-java-produces-negative-numbers) and *I cannot* guarantee, that thread id's always positive, even:

```
Math.abs(thread.getId() % 5) + 1
```

..and even [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412200/592355)(!):

```
(thread.getId() % 5 + 5) % 5 + 1
```

...could make sense.

Comment: Upvotes can be awarded to those who explain their answers ;)