# Why Does the calculation vary in python?

Tags: java, python, logical-operators, modulo

In java:
-2 % 6 = -2

In python
-2 % 6 = 4

Why this happens. could you please explain it?

Comment: [Best way to make Java's modulus behave like it should with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412179/12323248)