# Add no. of days in a date to get next date(excluding weekends)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an date, i need to add no. of days to get future date but weekends should be excluded.
i.e

```
input date = "9-DEC-2011";
No. of days to add  = '13';

next date should be "28-Dec-2011"
```

Here weekends(sat/sun) are not counted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add/subtract business days in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499944/add-subtract-business-days-in-javascript)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this

```
var startDate = "9-DEC-2011";
startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
var endDate = "", noOfDaysToAdd = 13, count = 0;
while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
    if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
       //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
       count++;
    }
}
alert(endDate);//You can format this date as per your requirement
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HaJpQ/)**

Comment: @Nishu - did you get a chance to take a look at this?

Comment: Thank Shanker... yeah i did.... i also implemented this logic as well, but main concern was to optimize the logic. Since if no. of days is like 30,40,50 and so on....., loop will execute that no. of times, do you think of any optimized solution??

Comment: I think we can optimize this let me give it a try whenever I get time.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli  Thank you this work for me. But i have custom weekend like 26Jan  national holiday  i want to exclude that also is there any solution

Comment: lets say I need to add weeks or months to the startDate then how can we do that? Considering the fact that a month can be of 28, 29, 30 or 31 days long.

Answer (score 13):

@ShankarSangoli

Here's a newer version which avoid recreating a Date object on each loop, note that it's wrapped in a function now.

```
function calcWorkingDays(fromDate, days) {
    var count = 0;
    while (count < days) {
        fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (fromDate.getDay() != 0 && fromDate.getDay() != 6) // Skip weekends
            count++;
    }
    return fromDate;
}
alert(calcWorkingDays(new Date("9/DEC/2011"), 13));
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an elegant solution without any looping or external library:

```js
function addBusinessDaysToDate(date, days) {
  var day = date.getDay();

  date = new Date(date.getTime());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days + (day === 6 ? 2 : +!day) + (Math.floor((days - 1 + (day % 6 || 1)) / 5) * 2));
  return date;
}

var date = "9-DEC-2011";
var newDate = addBusinessDaysToDate(new Date(date.replace(/-/g, "/")), 13);
console.log(newDate.toString().replace(/\S+\s(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*/, '$2-$1-$3')); // alerts "28-Dec-2011"
```

Comment: It is an excelent solution. It works even if the start date is on Saturday or Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

or you can be like this

```
function addWeekdays(date, weekdays) {
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    var i = 0;
    while (i < weekdays) {
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        var day = newDate.getDay();
        if (day > 1 && day < 7) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return newDate;
}
var currentDate = new Date('10/31/2014');
var targetDate = addWeekdays(currentDate, 45);
alert(targetDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/):**

```js
const DATE_FORMAT = 'D-MMM-YYYY';
const SUNDAY = 0; // moment day index
const SATURDAY = 6; // moment day index
const WEEKENDS = [SATURDAY, SUNDAY];

function addBusinessDays(stringDate, numberOfDays, dateFormat = DATE_FORMAT) {
  const date = moment(stringDate, dateFormat);
    
  let count = 0;
        
  while (count < numberOfDays) {
    date.add(1, 'day');

    // Skip weekends
    if (WEEKENDS.includes(date.day())) {
      continue;
    }

    // Increment count
    count++;
  }
    
  return date.format(dateFormat);
}

// Test cases
console.log(addBusinessDays('3-Mar-2021', 1)); // 4-Mar-2021
console.log(addBusinessDays('3-Mar-2021', 2)); // 5-Mar-2021
console.log(addBusinessDays('3-Mar-2021', 3)); // 8-Mar-2021
console.log(addBusinessDays('3-Mar-2021', 4)); // 9-Mar-2021
console.log(addBusinessDays('3-Mar-2021', 5)); // 10-Mar-2021
console.log(addBusinessDays('9-Dec-2011', 13)); // 28-Dec-2011
console.log(addBusinessDays('10-Dec-2011', 13)); // 28-Dec-2011 (Saturday, so remain on Friday)
console.log(addBusinessDays('11-Dec-2011', 13)); // 28-Dec-2011 (Sunday, so remain on Friday)
console.log(addBusinessDays('12-Dec-2011', 13)); // 29-Dec-2011
console.log(addBusinessDays('13-Dec-2011', 13)); // 30-Dec-2011
console.log(addBusinessDays('14-Dec-2011', 13)); // 2-Jan-2012
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this can return a weekend for numberOfDays < 5

Comment: You're right @Matt! I've added extra handling for that inside this codesnippet

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but all the previous answers are iterating over the days one by one. That could be inefficient for a large number of days. This works for me, assuming `days` is a positive int and the `startDate` is a working day:

```js
function addWorkingDates(startDate, days) {
  const current_day = startDate.getDay() - 1; // Week day, starting on Monday
  const weekend_days = 2 * parseInt((current_day + days) / 5);
  startDate.setDate(changed_to.getDate() + days + weekend_days);
}

addWorkingDates(new Date(),5)
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it was more intuitive to me to try this recursively. This version doesn't account for holidays, but you could change the `isValid` function to check whatever.

```js
function addWeekdaysToDate(date, numberToAdd) {
  var isValid = function(d) { return d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6 }
  if(Math.abs(numberToAdd) > 1) {
    return addWeekdaysToDate(
      addWeekdaysToDate(date, Math.sign(numberToAdd)),
      numberToAdd - Math.sign(numberToAdd)
    )
  } else if(Math.abs(numberToAdd) === 1) {
    var result = new Date(date)
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + Math.sign(numberToAdd))
    if(isValid(result)) {
      return result
    } else {
      return addWeekdaysToDate(result, Math.sign(numberToAdd))
    }
  } else if(numberToAdd === 0) {
    return date
  }
  return false
}

console.log(addWeekdaysToDate(new Date(), 1))
console.log(addWeekdaysToDate(new Date(), 5))
console.log(addWeekdaysToDate(new Date(), -7))
```

In [certain browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) you may need a polyfill for `Math.sign`:

```
Math.sign = Math.sign || function(x) {
  x = +x; // convert to a number
  if (x === 0 || isNaN(x)) {
    return Number(x);
  }
  return x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
<script language="javascript">

function getDateExcludeWeekends(startDay, startMonth, startYear, daysToAdd) {
var sdate = new Date();
var edate = new Date();
var dayMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
sdate.setFullYear(startYear,startMonth,startDay);
edate.setFullYear(startYear,startMonth,startDay+daysToAdd);
var weekendDays = 0;
while (sdate <= edate) {
    var day = sdate.getDay()
    if (day == 0 || day == 6) {
        weekendDays++;
    }
    sdate = new Date(+sdate + dayMilliseconds);
} 
sdate.setFullYear(startYear,startMonth,startDay + weekendDays+daysToAdd);
return sdate;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the next working day, from a specific date, use the following code...

```
function getNextWorkingDay(originalDate) {
    var nextWorkingDayFound = false;
    var nextWorkingDate = new Date();
    var dateCounter = 1;

    while (!nextWorkingDayFound) {
        nextWorkingDate.setDate(originalDate.getDate() + dateCounter);
        dateCounter++;

        if (!isDateOnWeekend(nextWorkingDate)) {
            nextWorkingDayFound = true;
        } 
    }

    return nextWorkingDate;
}

function isDateOnWeekend(date) {
    if (date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function honouring weekends and also given holiday array

```
var startDate = "10/18/2023";
var endDate = "11/25/2023";

function isSameDate(date1, date2) {
  // Compare exact dates with miliseconds
  return date1.getTime() === date2.getTime();
}

function isWeekEnd(date) {
  //If Day of given date falls between Monday to Friday then return False
  day = date.getDay();
  if (day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
      return false;
  }
  //Else return true
  return true;
}

function isHoliday(date) {
  //List of holidays provided
  var usHolidays=["11/10/2023","11/23/2023","12/25/2023","01/02/2024","01/15/2024"];
  
  //Iterate through all holidays and check if given date falls on holiday
  for(i = 0; i < usHolidays.length; i++) {
    holiday = usHolidays[i];
    
    //Convert String to Date
    holiday = new Date(holiday);
    
    //normalize to beginning of the day 
    holiday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    
    if (isSameDate(date, holiday)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function calculateBusinessDays(startDate, endDate) {
  // make copies we can normalize without changing passed in objects    
  var start = new Date(startDate);
  var end = new Date(endDate);

  // initial total
  var totalBusinessDays = 0;

  // normalize both start and end to beginning of the day
  start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  end.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  
  // start from the next day
  var current = new Date(start);
  current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
  var day;
  // loop through each day, checking
  while (current <= end) {
      //add to business day if its not weekend or holiday
      if (!isWeekEnd(current) && !isHoliday(current)){
        ++totalBusinessDays;
      }
      //move one day forward
      current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return totalBusinessDays;
}

var totalBusinessDays = calculateBusinessDays(startDate, endDate);
console.log(totalBusinessDays);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
function calculate() {
  var noOfDaysToAdd = 13;
  var startDate = "9-DEC-2011";
  startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
  var endDate = "";
  count = 0;
  while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
    if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = endDate;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Date of book delivery: <span id="result"></span><br /><br />
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Calculate" />
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer, explaining what you are showing and why this is solving the OP's problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer