# How to find date after 60 days form a particular date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I want to find date in dd/mm/Y format after 60 days from any date submitted by user by date-picker in dd/mm/yy format.
I tried searching for it but all i get is 60 days from today's date!!!
Pls Help!!!

Comment: Well.. I am pretty new to javascript.
Actually I am working with php but i need a javascript code to do this and change automatically a text box's value. So I tried doing some basic things with date() but no result!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three distinct subproblems here.  First, parse the input in
dd/mm/yy format into an object suitable for doing the date arithmetic.
Do the +60 days arithmetic.  Format the result in dd/mm/Y format.

Javascript has a Date object which is fine for doing the simple
arithmetic you need, in my opinion.  Adding 60 days to a date is as
easy as

```
givenDate.setDate(givenDate.getDate() + 60)
```

The setDate method takes care of out of range values, see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

For parsing you can extract year, month, and day from your string in
the dd/mm/yy format (basically using the string split() method, and
feeding the three values to the Date constructor, as in

```
new Date(year, month, day)
```

As for formatting, you can use the Date object getter functions to build
up your string.  See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Full code:

```
function parse(dateStr) {
  var parts = dateStr.split('/').map(function (digits) {
    // Beware of leading zeroes...
    return parseInt(digits, 10);
  });
  return new Date(1900 + parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
}

function format(date) {
  var parts = [
    date.getDate(),
    date.getMonth(),
    date.getYear() + 1900
  ];
  if (parts[0] < 10) {
    parts[0] = '0' + parts[0];
  }
  if (parts[1] < 10) {
    parts[1] = '0' + parts[1];
  }
  return parts.join('/');
}

function add(date, days) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

console.log(format(add(parse('11/06/83'), 60)));
// Outputs: 09/08/1983
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to exclude weekend, the use following:**

```
var startDate = "9-DEC-2011";
startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
var endDate = "", noOfDaysToAdd = 13, count = 0;
while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
    if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
       //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
       count++;
    }
}
// above code  excludes weekends.
alert(endDate);//You can format this date as per your requirement
```

You can refer following question for the same :

[Add no. of days in a date to get next date(excluding weekends)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451190/add-no-of-days-in-a-date-to-get-next-dateexcluding-weekends)

**If you want to include weekend, the use following:**

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 32);
// output will be  Tue Jan 21 2014 15:55:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: Its good.. But what if i hv to include weekends too.. I tried changing that 6 to 7 but still not getting the answer required..

Comment: Thats even more simpler, updated the answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version using the JavaScript date object:

```
function toTheFuture(date, days){
  var split = userInput.split("/"),
      //Split up the date and then process it into a Date object
      userDate = new Date(+split[2]+2000, +split[1]-1, +split[0]);

  //Add your days!
  userDate.setDate(userDate.getDate() + days);

  //Return your new dd/mm/yyyy formatted string!
  return addZero(userDate.getDate())+"/"+addZero(userDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+userDate.getFullYear()
}

//Ensures that if getDate() returns 8 for example, we still get it to output 08
function addZero(num){
  if(num<10){
    num = "0"+num;
  }
  return ""+num;
}

toTheFuture("09/05/13", 60);
//Will return 08/07/2013
```

The JavaScript date object is slightly more annoying to use than most would like, there are quite a few libraries (e.g. [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)) that simplify it to work like you would expect