# Alert if selected date is within five working day from current date(today)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a datepicker with ID "dtpicker".

I need to make sure that user will get an alert popup if  selected date is within five working days from current day(today).

I have a almost working solution:

```
function DateRule()
{
  var dt = new Date(); 
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 5);
  var date = dt.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  userdatepick = NWF$("#" + datepicker).val();

  if (userdatepick < date)
  {
  alert("Reminder: you have selected a startdate that is earlier then five workingdays from todays date")
  }
}
```

I tested this with todays date and it works almost as it suppose to when I select dates throught datepicker between 2010-10-18 - 2010-10-22 I get the alert reminder which is correct. When I select 2010-10-23 I dont get reminder alert, but it should since its weekend day and not working day. 2010-10-25 should not give reminder thought.

Could a solution be to ignore weekend days when adding five days to current date(today). For an example when I add five days to my variable It jumps over weekend days?

Any help or tips is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at http://momentjs.com/. Makes working with dates so much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6499944/1493235

Comment: @JohannesB thats a 5 years old question

Comment: This is really a duplicate of [*many questions*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+business+days) that have been asked before about adding or subtracting business days from a date.

Comment: An old question is not necessarily a bad or non-relevant question @Obsivus , people struggle with the same programming problems every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate something like the below one.

```js
function validateDate(txtDate) {

  var selectedDate = new Date(txtDate),
    date = new Date(),
    days = 5;

  while (days > 0 && (date = new Date(date)) < selectedDate) {
    date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    if (!isWeekend(date)) {
      days -= 1;
    }
  }

  if (days !== 0) {
    console.log("Reminder: you have selected a startdate that is earlier then five workingdays from todays date");
  }

}

var isWeekend = function(date) {
  var dt = new Date(date);

  if (dt.getDay() == 6 || dt.getDay() == 0 /* check here for holidays */) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

validateDate("Oct 23, 2016");
```

Comment: Note that the *setDate* method returns the time value of the updated date, so `date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);` sets *date* to a number, not a Date object.

Comment: @RobG Yes, But in `isWeekend` function, we are constructing date object again

Comment: "We"? Why not just delete the `date =` part and keep it as a Date? Then there is no need to create a new Date in *isWeekend*. ;-)

Comment: if you remove `date = ` part, then `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)` will throw error since `date` is a number (Time).

Comment: No, it will not. The right hand side is evaluated first, while *date* is still a Date. The method returns a number that you then assign to *date* so that its value becomes a number, not a Date.

Comment: Yes, it is. Did you tried the above code without `date =` part?. I tried, throws `date.getDate is not a function` error. Because first time, as you told it still Date but for second iteration, it becomes number.

Comment: I don't know what code you are running, but changing `date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);` to `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);` should not and does not throw an error. Please post the code that does.