# Javascript logic to find the date based on the given number that is before or after excluding weekends

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have a strange requirement where I need a find the date based on given number and type = before/after parameter

i.e., for example

```
Date = new Date() - 3/8/2020 (It can be any date)
type = before
days = 7(It can be any number)
```

Now I need to find the date excluding the weekends.

In this case it would be **23/7/2020** .Because **2/8,1/8,26/7,25/7 are weekends**, so those should be **excluded** and calculated.

Simillarly if **type = after** , date will be **12/8/2020** .In this case **8/8 and 9/8 are weekends** and those will be **excluded**.

So how can we implement this as function that takes **date,days,type as parameters and return the date.**

i.e.,

```
function calculateDate(day,days,type){
  /* Some logic 
     if(new Date(day).getDay() !== 6||7){};
  */
 return date
}
```

**Note : I cant use any libraries like moment/dayjs etc as I have restrictions with the development tool Im using..I need to implement in pure javascript logic**

Can any javascript datetime expert  help me on this as I couldn't crack this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to say you want the last weekday? or is it minus x number of working days?

Comment: I'd use the dayjs library for this.

Comment: Or [moment](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @Liam not exactly I need the date which is 7 days before excluding the weekends

Comment: right so minus x number of working days then..

Comment: @JoshWulf I cant use any libraries as there are restrictions with the tool Im using

Comment: Have a look at [this then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499944/add-subtract-business-days-in-javascript). There are multiple solutions to this problem if you google a bit

Comment: @Liam here I have given 7 just as an example..It can be any number

Comment: There are many questions and answers already about [adding and subtracting business days](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+business+days). Write some code, then ask if you have problems. Simply asking for code is not a suitable question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const date = new Date()
let days = 7 // Adjust accordingly
let delta = -1 // Set +1 to check 'days after' instead of 'days before'

while (days > 0) {
  // Remove a day
  date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + delta) 
  // Check if weekend (adjust your days number according to your needs)
  const isWeekend = date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0
  // If it is not a weekend, reduce the number of days to subtract
  if (!isWeekend) {
    days = days - 1
  }
}

return date
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Im looking for the same.It worked.:)