# Previous Month Showing undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function calculateTime() {
    var Make_It_12_Hour = true;
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hour1 = currentTime.getHours() - 1; 
    var hour2 = currentTime.getHours();
    var hour3 = currentTime.getHours() + 1;
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var minute1 = currentTime.getMinutes() - 1;
    var minute2 = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var minute3 = currentTime.getMinutes() + 1;

    if (Make_It_12_Hour) {
        hour1 = hour1 % 12;
        hour1 = (hour1) ? hour1 : 12;
        hour2 = hour2 % 12;
        hour2 = (hour2) ? hour2 : 12;
        hour3 = hour3 % 12;
        hour3 = (hour3) ? hour3 : 12;

        if (hour1 < 0)  hour1 = "11";
        if (hour3 > 12) hour3 = "1";
        if (hour1 < 10) hour1 = "0" + hour1;
        if (hour2 < 10) hour2 = "0" + hour2;
        if (hour3 < 10) hour3 = "0" + hour3;
        if (minute1 < 0) minute1 = "59";
        if (minute3 > 59) minute3 = "1";
        if (minute1 < 10) minute1 = "0" + minute1;
        if (minute2 < 10) minute2 = "0" + minute2;  
        if (minute3 < 10) minute3 = "0" + minute3;
    } else {
        if (minute1 < 0) minute1 = "59";
        if (minute3 > 59) minute3 = "1";
        if (minute1 < 10) minute1 = "0" + minute1;
        if (minute2 < 10) minute2 = "0" + minute2;
        if (minute3 < 10) minute3 = "0" + minute3;
        if (hour1 < 0) hour1 = "23";
        if (hour3 > 23) hour3 = "0";
        if (hour1 < 10) hour1 = "0" + hour1;
        if (hour2 < 10) hour2 = "0" + hour2;
        if (hour3 < 10) hour3 = "0" + hour3;  
    }

    document.getElementById("time1-1").innerText = hour1;
    document.getElementById("time1-2").innerText = hour2;
    document.getElementById("time1-3").innerText = hour3;
    document.getElementById("time2-1").innerText = minute1;
    document.getElementById("time2-2").innerText = minute2;
    document.getElementById("time2-3").innerText = minute3;
}

function calculateDate() {

    var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"); 
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var day1 = (currentTime.getDate() - 1).toString();
    var day2 = currentTime.getDate().toString();
    var day3 = (currentTime.getDate() + 1).toString();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth();

    if (day1.length == 1) day1 = "0" + day1;
    if (day2.length == 1) day2 = "0" + day2;
    if (day3.length == 1) day3 = "0" + day3;

    document.getElementById("date1-1").innerText = months[month - 1];
    document.getElementById("date1-2").innerText = months[month];
    document.getElementById("date1-3").innerText = months[month + 1];
    document.getElementById("date2-1").innerText = day1;
    document.getElementById("date2-2").innerText = day2;
    document.getElementById("date2-3").innerText = day3;
}

calculateTime();
calculateDate();
setInterval(calculateTime, 2000);
setInterval(calculateDate, 60000);
```

Hello the code listed above works properly. The month shows current and next month however this line outputs undefined:

```
 document.getElementById("date1-1").innerText = months[month - 1];
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. If I modify the line from -1 to +1 it shows current month.

Full code in [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/V45zf/).

Comment: If month is January, then month = 0, month -1 = -1, months[-1] === undefined

Answer (score 1):

You obtain the current month like this:

```
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
```

Which is 0 because months are 0-based in JavaScript and we are in January.

You then try to access the array `months` at the index `month - 1`, which is -1. `months[-1]` is `undefined`.

You can use the modulo operator to avoid this behavior (modifications based on [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-not-behaving))

```
months[(((month - 1) % 12) + 12) % 12]
```

or, if you add to to `Number` prototype as it is done in the other question

```
months[(month - 1).mod(12)]
```

For example, with `month = 0` we obtain `months[11]`.