# Why does CoffeeScript use %% for modulo instead of the standard javascript operator %

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, operators, modulo

In the [CoffeeScript documentation on operators](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) it says that you can use `%%` for true mathematical modulo, but there is no explanation as to why this is different from the "modulo operator" `%` in JavaScript.

Further down it says that `a %% b` in CoffeeScript is equivalent to writing `(a % b + b) % b` in JavaScript but this seem to produce the same results for most simple cases.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I did find the answer in another StackOverflow question and answer [JavaScript % (modulo) gives a negative result for negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-not-behaving) and [I wanted to share it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for people who like me only looked for a "CoffeeScript" related explanations and thus have a hard time finding the correct answer.

The reason for using `a %% b` which compiles to `(a % b + b) % b` is that for negative number, like `-5 % 3`, JavaScript will produce a negative number `-5 % 3 = -2` while the correct mathematical answer should be `-5 % 3 = 1`.

The accepted answer refers to [an article on the JavaScript modulo bug](http://javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm) which explains it well.

Answer (score 2):

Made no sense for me at first, so I believe it needs an example

```
check = (a,b) ->
  c = (b*Math.floor(a/b)) + a%b
  d = (b*Math.floor(a/b)) + a%%b
  console.log(
    [c, c == a]
    [d, d == a]
  )

check  78, 33 # [ 78, true ] [ 78, true ]
check -78, 33 # [ -111, false ] [ -78, true ]

###
 78 mod 33 = 12
-78 mod 33 = 21

check:  78 = 33 *  2 + 12
check: -78 = 33 * -3 + 21
###
```

Looks like modulo is a mathematical trick to be able to use one formula for all numbers instead of one for negatives and second for positives. Don't know if it's more than just a trick and have some intrinsic meaning though.