# Trans-compiling Python aks primality test to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I am trans-compiling this Python code:

```
def expand_x_1(p):
    ex = [1]
    for i in range(p):
        ex.append(ex[-1] * -(p-i) / (i+1))
    return ex[::-1]
def aks_test(p):
    if p < 2: return False
    ex = expand_x_1(p)
    ex[0] += 1
    return not any(mult % p for mult in ex[0:-1])
for p in range(101):
    if aks_test(p):
        print(p)
```

Into JavaScript. Here is what I have done so far:

```
function expand_x_1(p){
    var ex = [1];
    for(i = 0; i < p; i++){
        ex.push(ex[ex.length - 2] * -(p-i) / (i+1));
    }
    return ex.reverse();
}
function aks_test(p){
    if(p < 2)
        return false;
    var ex = expand_x_1(p);
    ex[0] += 1;
    // the return part right here is what I need help with.
}
// Python equivalent of any()
function any(iterable){
    for(element in iterable)
        if(element)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I just need help converting this line of Python code into JavaScript:

```
return not any(mult % p for mult in ex[0:-1])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript implementation of `any` will not work with Arrays. You better be using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (and [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for Python's `all`).

Since we don't have generator expressions, in JavaScript, you can do

```
return ex.slice(0, -1).some(function(currentItem) {
    currentItem % p;
});
```

We [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array, so we can exclude the last element.

Comment: Hmm, my script still isn't working correctly even when I try your suggestion.

Comment: Be aware that in JavaScript, the `%` operator is not a true modulo. It will only work as Python's does for positive numbers. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-not-behaving) to help solve that issue.

Comment: @jshanley I tried implementing your suggestion but it still doesn't work…

Comment: @Progo not working correctly, doesn't give me any clues

Comment: @Progo Sorry, I have no idea about AKS testing algorithm

Answer (score 0):

First, define a modulo function to [make sure the modulo behaves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-not-behaving) the same way as in Python:

```js
function modulo(a, b) {
    return ((a % b) + b) % b;
}
```

The 'not any' line really just means that you want to return true if none of the iterations of the modulo get a result of 0. You can't do a list comprehension in JS, but you can get the same result by doing something like this.

```js
// just use length-1 instead of slicing array
for (var i = 0; i < ex.length - 1; i++) {
  var mult = ex[i];
  // modulo mult by p
  var test = modulo(mult, p);
  // return false if any modulo result is 0
  if (test === 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
// will only make it this far if all modulos !== 0
return true;
```

--EDIT--

I only expanded it to make it easier to follow, you could make the for-loop much simpler:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < ex.length - 1; i++) {
  if (modulo(ex[i], p) === 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion, but now it is just behaving strangely: http://jsfiddle.net/Progo/aqN94/