# javascript (boolean ^ boolean)

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I'm working on rewriting some Javascript-code to work in Excel VBA.
I've manage to translate almost all of the Javascript-code thanks to searching on this website! However, there is some code I can't understand what it's doing precisely.
This is the bit of Javascript-code:

```
var k = x % y;
return (k != 0 && (k > 0 ^ y > 0) && isFinite(y)) ? k + y : k;
```

The first line is clear to me. k is the remainder of x/y.
In the second line, modulo gets the value of either k+y or k. This is decided by (k!=0 && (k > 0 ^ y > 0) && isFinite(y))

Could somebody explain to me step by step how I should be reading this code? Especially the &&(k>0^y>0)&& is puzzling me.

This is how far I seem to be getting till now:

Example 1: x=9 and y=4

```
k = 9%4 = 9/4=2 with remainder 1    So: k=1
(1!=0&&(1>0^4>0)&&isFinite(4))   (True AND (True^True) AND True)  =  True?
```

Example 1: x=9 and y=1

```
k = 9%1 = 9/1=9 with remainder 0    So: k=0
(0!=0&&(0>0^1>0)&&isFinite(1))  (False AND (False^True) AND True)  =  False?
```

If I would think purely mathematically, then I would guess that the part (False^True) should be read like (0^1) = 0 = False.

Comment: You're correct. I'll change the code to the original one.

Comment: The `^` operator is the XOR, or EXCLUSIVE OR, operator. It only returns true if and only if one value is true. If both are true, or both are false, the result is false.

Comment: Above code implements the 'mathematical' modulo operator, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-gives-a-negative-result-for-negative-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step explanation of the critical part as evaluated by the language:

`(k != 0 && (k > 0 ^ y > 0) && isFinite(y)) ? k + y : k;`

- `(k != 0 && (k > 0 ^ y > 0)`: `true` if and only if 1. and 2. below is `true`

  1. `k != 0`: `true` if `k` is not in `0, '0', 0.0, '0.0'`
  2. `(k > 0 ^ y > 0)`: `true` if and only if one of 1. and 2. is `true`

     1. k > 0: `true` if and only if `k` is a `Number` or numeric `String` above `0`
     2. y > 0: `true` if and only if `y` is a `Number` or numeric `String` above `0`
- `isFinite(y))`: `true` if `y` is not one of `undefined, Object, Array, Infinity, -Infinity, ...` (further native objects) or a non-numeric `String`
- `(k != 0 && (k > 0 ^ y > 0) && isFinite(y))`: `true` if and only if both parts above were `true`. The ternary `?` operator will return the 1st post-expression `k + y` if the pre-expression is `true` and the 2nd post-expression `k` otherwise.

In more general terms the take-away lessons are:

- comparisons in JS are complex: `String` is often cast to `Number` and different functions have different behavior on native objects (`isFinite(null) === true` but `isFinite(undefined) === false`). Therefore generally always prefer using `===` and `!==`.
- JS uses [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) on boolean operators
- `^` is the exclusive `OR` aka `XOR` operator
- `?` is the ternary `if` operator which equals `if ... do ... else do ...`

Answer (score 1):

The `^` operator is the XOR, or EXCLUSIVE OR, bitwise operator. It only returns true if and only if one value is true. If both are true, or both are false, the result is false

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR:

`a      b       a XOR b
0      0       0
0      1       1
1      0       1
1      1       0`

As to why your second example returns FALSE, it's because you're using AND logic:

`FALSE && (FALSE ^ TRUE) && TRUE` results in `FALSE && TRUE && TRUE` which equates to `FALSE`.