# Rounding up to the nearest multiple of 5

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a Javascript function rounding up to the nearest multiple of 5.  But you only round up if the difference between the variable and the roundup to the multiple of 5 is less than 3.  (so 53 would round up to 55, but 52 would stay 52.)

Also if the grade is < 38 its an F.

The code below is what I have but it is not running properly.  How can I fix it?

Thanks!!

```js
grade = 71
function roundGrade (grade) {
const remainder = grade % 5
if (grade < 38) {
 return "fail";  }
else if (remainder >= 3) {
 grade; }
else if (remainder < 3) {
  grade-remainder+5
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the remainder is `3` or above, you simply need to add `5` and subtract the remainder, which can be done with `grade += 5 - remainder`. Also note that you don't need your second `else if` conditional at all, as you only want to modify `grade` if the remainder is greater than or equal to `3`. Finally, you need to make sure that your function actually **returns** `grade`  with `return grade`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function roundGrade(grade) {
  const remainder = grade % 5;
  if (grade < 38) {
    return "fail";
  } else if (remainder >= 3) {
    grade += 5 - remainder;
  }
  return grade;
}

console.log(roundGrade(71));
console.log(roundGrade(74));
```

Comment: Thank you!  and What would I do if it was an array of grades?

Answer (score 2):

calculate the remainder of `grade / 5` and add it to the grade if the remaining is less than `3`, otherwise return the grade as is.

```js
const grade1 = 71
const grade2 = 73
const grade3 = 33

function roundGrade(grade) {
  if (grade < 38) return "fail"

  const rem = grade % 5;
  return rem < 3 ? grade : grade + (5 - rem)
}

console.log(roundGrade(grade1))
console.log(roundGrade(grade2))
console.log(roundGrade(grade3))
```

Comment: The `%` operator doesn't  return modulo, it returns the remainder, see [*JavaScript % (modulo) gives a negative result for negative numbers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-gives-a-negative-result-for-negative-numbers). It's a [*MultiplicativeOperator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators) that behaves per [*12.7.3.3 Applying the % Operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-applying-the-mod-operator). :-)

Comment: @RobG thnx for the clarification :) never been good with terminologies