# Cycle through objects in an array by setting state with a button React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have some data I would like to cycle through:

```
const data = {
  names: [
    {
      name: "Jordan"
      // additional data
    },
    {
      name: "Holly"
      // additional data
    },
    {
      name: "Sean"
      // additional data
    }
  ]
};
```

Using `useState` hook, I start my data from the index of 0:

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(data.names[0]);
```

How can I cycle through the objects in my array using state? I have created a button that calls `handleClick`, how can I +1 through the array?

```
function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(data.names[0]);

  function handleClick() {
    setIndex(); // Help!
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{index.name}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Change name</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-black-qj5w6)

Comment: `const [index, setIndex] = useState(0); function handleClick() { setIndex(i => (i + 1) % data.names.length); }` then use `data.names[index]` instead of `index.name`

Comment: Tried but doesn't seem to work?

Comment: It should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't set the element from the array in the state. Instead use the current `index`. In the handler add 1 to the `index` on each click, and to circle the names get the remainder from the length. Whenever the `index` is equal to the array's length, the remainder would be 0.

Note: the `mod()` function is needed for backwards cycling, since the remainder operator (`%`) doesn't work well with negative numbers. It was taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17323608/5157454).

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m;

function App({ names }) {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const forwards = useCallback(() => 
    setIndex(state => mod(state + 1, names.length))
  , [setIndex, names]);
  
  const backwards = useCallback(() => 
    setIndex(state => mod(state - 1, names.length))
  , [setIndex, names]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{names[index].name}</h1>
      <button onClick={backwards}>Backwards</button>
      <button onClick={forwards}>Forwards</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const data = {"names":[{"name":"Jordan"},{"name":"Holly"},{"name":"Sean"}]};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App {...data} />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's great! Especially with the looping - If I added a second button to cycle backwards, how could I do that?

Comment: Ideally you would create another function, and use -1. However, JS % operator doesn't do well with negative numbers. I've added a `mod()` function, taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-gives-a-negative-result-for-negative-numbers), that gets the remainder from negative numbers as well.