# How to get a date object from a different timezone in utc format in js

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am located in the PDT timezone. When I type in `new Date()` into the browser's console, I get Tue `Aug 31 2021 09:43:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`.

Now, I want the date in the same format from the central time region.

So I want the time object to look like this: `Aug 31 2021 11:43:15 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

I've been reading the docs about Intl, Intl.DateTimeFormat() and toLocalTimeString() but can't seem to find it.

I tried `new Date().toLocaleString(undefined, { timeZone: "US/Central" })` which gives me "8/31/2021, 11:46:30 AM", which is correct but not the right format.

I tried new `Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'full', timeStyle: 'long', timeZone:"US/Central" }).format(new Date())` which also gives me a string and not a date object in UTC format.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no built–in method to do that in a simple way. But you can use [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) then arrange them yourself (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61721327/257182)). Also see [*How to format a JavaScript date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1919.3661)

Comment: BTW, [UTC is a time standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), not a format. The format you want is defined by ECMA-262 as that produced by [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date in JS is a tricky issue - I agree 100% with you:

I did it once the hard way:

1. **splitting** the resulting date object into parts
2. **concat** all the parts according to my desired custom format

Maybe not the most elegant way, but it worked.
Any suggestions from other contributors are very welcome.

**Edit:**
Added `let oTZPartsReduced = ...` in reply to valuable comment from @RobG

```js
let myTimeZone = new Date();
console.log(myTimeZone);
//console.log((myTimeZone.getTimezoneOffset()/60).toFixed(2));

// oTZ = otherTimeZone  (to keep it short)
let oTZ = new Date(myTimeZone).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "US/Central"});

let oTZFormatted;

let oTZParts = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  weekday: 'short',
  day:'2-digit',
  month: 'short',
  year: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  timeZone: 'US/Central' // <-- here it goes, your wished timeZone
}).formatToParts(new Date(myTimeZone));

oTZFormatted = oTZParts[2].value + ' ' + oTZParts[4].value + ' '+ oTZParts[6].value + ' '+ oTZParts[8].value + ':'+ oTZParts[10].value + ':'+ oTZParts[12].value + ' GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)';

// order within above array could vary due to language as @RobG stated - thanks
// hence following reduced version of above array:
let oTZPartsReduced = oTZParts.reduce((acc, part) => {
  if (part.type != 'literal') {
    acc[part.type] = part.value;
  }
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

oTZFormatted = oTZPartsReduced.month + ' ' + oTZPartsReduced.day + ' '+ oTZPartsReduced.year + ' '+ oTZPartsReduced.hour + ':'+ oTZPartsReduced.minute + ':'+ oTZPartsReduced.second + ' GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)';

console.log(oTZFormatted);
console.log('Array of Parts for reference:');
console.log(oTZParts);
console.log('Object (reduced) of Parts for reference:');
console.log(oTZPartsReduced);
```

Comment: The order of the parts is determined by the language so may change (e.g. en-US, en-GB, en-CA are all different). Consider using *reduce* to convert the array to an object with `{part.type: part.value}`, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61721327/257182). The only duplicate types/names are the literals, which most don't care about.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for your valuable comment - excelent. I edited my code accordingly, so now we have both versions: _array_ and _reduced to object_. Again thanks and a big upvote for that 