# Function that takes an array and returns elements inside rotated n spaces in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, rotation

Create a function named "rotate" that takes an array and returns a new one with the elements inside rotated n spaces.

If n is greater than 0 it should rotate the array to the right. If n is less than 0 it should rotate the array to the left. If n is 0, then it should return the array unchanged.

Example:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

rotate(data, 1) // => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
rotate(data, 2) // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
rotate(data, 3) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
rotate(data, 4) // => [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
rotate(data, 5) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

rotate(data, 0) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

rotate(data, -1) // => [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
rotate(data, -2) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
rotate(data, -3) // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
rotate(data, -4) // => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
rotate(data, -5) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Furthermore the method should take ANY array of objects and perform this operation on them:

```
rotate(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1)     // => ['c', 'a', 'b']
rotate([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 1)     // => [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]
rotate([true, true, false], 1) // => [false, true, true]
```

Finally, the rotation shouldn't be limited by the indices available in the array. Meaning that if we exceed the indices of the array it keeps rotating.

Example:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rotate(data, 7)     // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
rotate(data, 11)    // => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
rotate(data, 12478) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Is it a codewars task?

Comment: yes, it is, I am stuck with this one for a few days, that's why I asked for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could basically do this with a `while` loop and `increment` or `decrement` based on the number parameter, if its positive or negative.

```js
function rotate(data, n) {
  const output = [...data]

  if (n === 0) {
    return data
  }

  const neg = n < 0
  const last = output.length - 1
  const toIndex = neg ? last : 0
  const index = neg ? 0 : last

  while ((neg ? n++ : n--) !== 0) {
    output.splice(toIndex, 0, output.splice(index, 1)[0])
  }

  return output
}


var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(rotate(data, 2)) // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(rotate(data, 3)) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
console.log(rotate(data, 4)) // => [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
console.log(rotate(data, 5)) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


console.log(rotate(data, -1)) // => [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
console.log(rotate(data, -2)) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
console.log(rotate(data, -3)) // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(rotate(data, -4)) // => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(rotate(data, -5)) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(rotate(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1))
console.log(rotate([true, true, false], 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-mutating example avoiding loops:

```js
const rotate = (arr, n) => {

  const i = ((n % arr.length) + arr.length) % arr.length

  if (!i) return [...arr]

  return [...arr.slice(-i), ...arr.slice(0, arr.length - i)]

}
```

### Explanation

The basic idea is that the single most important thing in this calculation is the effective starting index based on the arguments given. We achieve this through the [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operand which helps us work out the index based on the length of the array and a number which can be greater than the length of the array.

i.e:

```js
const i = n % arr.length
```

Because we are wanting to use negative numbers too, we need to adapt our modulo operation slightly (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467559/726766)) as JavaScript's version of the modulo is slightly different to other implementations when it comes to dealing with negative numbers.

so..

```
const i = ((n % arr.length) + arr.length) % arr.length
```

Then it's a simple case of using [spread operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) from ES6 in order to stitch together the new array from the end/start of the old array:

```js
return [...arr.slice(-i), ...arr.slice(0, arr.length - i)]
```

This results in a function that passes all the OPs tests:

```js
const rotate = (arr, n) => {

  const i = ((n % arr.length) + arr.length) % arr.length

  if (!i) return arr

  return [...arr.slice(-i), ...arr.slice(0, arr.length - i)]

}

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(rotate(data, 1)) // => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(rotate(data, 2)) // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(rotate(data, 3)) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
console.log(rotate(data, 4)) // => [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
console.log(rotate(data, 5)) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(rotate(data, 0)) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(rotate(data, -1)) // => [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
console.log(rotate(data, -2)) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
console.log(rotate(data, -3)) // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(rotate(data, -4)) // => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(rotate(data, -5)) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(rotate(data, 7)) // => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(rotate(data, 11)) // => [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(rotate(data, 12478)) // => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Here's the TypeScript version:

```js
const rotate = <T,>(arr: T[], n: number): T[] => {

  const i = ((n % arr.length) + arr.length) % arr.length;

  if (!i) return [...arr]

  return [...arr.slice(-i), ...arr.slice(0, arr.length - i)]

}
```