# Mapping values to sequential range

Tags: javascript, math, range, mapping

I get values in the Range of -360 to 360 that should be mapped to a sequence corresponding to fractions of 45.
(Or any other value, Im really more interested in the mapping algorithm than the use case here).

| IN | -360 | -315 | -270 | -225 | -180 | -135 | -90 | -45 | 0 | 45 | 90 | 135 | 180 | 225 | 270 | 325 | 360 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| STEP | 0 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 0 |
| OUT | 0 | 45 | 0 | -45 | 0 | 45 | 0 | -45 | 0 | 45 | 0 | -45 | 0 | 45 | 0 | -45 | 0 |

Is there a linear Transformation I can/should use?
Or how do I set up a mapping like:

```
var mapRange = function(base_range, target_range, s) {
  return target_range[0] + (s - base_range[0]) * (target_range[1] - target_range[0]) / (base_range[1] - base_range[0]);
};
```

for this?

edit: Added the desired output. Thought breaking it down to a -1 to 1 range would imply the trivial *45

Comment: You talking about mapping to *... a sequence corresponding to fractions of 45...* but I don't see that. I see inputs that differ by 45 being mapped to {-1, 0, 1} with the output a repeating pattern of 0, 1, 0, -1.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk edited for clarification. As I'm more interested in the method of mapping to sequences, I thought the *45 after the mapping step would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave), which can be computed using this formula:

```
4 * a / p * abs(((i - p / 4) % p) - p / 2) - a
```

Note that `%` in the formula is modulo, not remainder, so in JavaScript we need to define a function to return the expected result (see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder), and some sample functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-gives-a-negative-result-for-negative-numbers)).

In your case, `a` (the amplitude) is 1, and `p` (the period) is 180.  You can write a function to compute the value and then use it to compute individual values:

```js
const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m

const triWave = (i, a, p) => 4 * a / p * Math.abs(mod(i - p / 4, p) - p / 2) - a

console.log(triWave(22.5, 1, 180))
console.log(triWave(-56.25, 1, 180))

const inp = Array.from({ length: 17 }, (_, i) => -360 + 45 * i)
const steps = inp.map(i => triWave(i, 1, 180))

console.log(steps)
```

Comment: That works for whole number dividents of 45. But as I need a mapping, the stepping is off for all other values. For Input: 22.5 I'd expect the output 0.5 in the [-1,1] range, stepping with your proposal would give 0.71 . Or another example: Input -56.25 should be mapped to -0.75, but the step sets it to -0.92

Comment: @D.icon ah... I just went from your sample data in the question. It wasn't clear that you wanted to interpolate linearly between those values as well. Give me a minute to edit...

Comment: @D.icon Sorry, got called away. please see my edit

Comment: perfect solution, especially that it is as versatile as I hoped!

Comment: @D.icon good to hear. I'm glad I could help