# I want to filter only odd negative numbers from an array. Why does n % 2 === 1 not work, but n % 2 !== 0 does?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a function that returns only negative odd numbers from an array.

```
const arr = [4, -7, -6]
```

I first tried:

```
let negativeOdd = arr.filter(n => n % 2 === 1 && n < 0);
return negativeOdd;
```

result was an empty array.  `[]`. The answer should be `[-5]`.

But when I replaced `n % 2 === 1` with `n % 2 !== 0`, it workded. I am new to JS and was hopeing somenone could help me understand why this is happening. Thank you.

Comment: Try `console.log(-5 % 2)`. What is the result?

Comment: `-5` is not even in the initial array

Comment: Modulo is not really modulo but more of remainder in JavaScript...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript % (modulo) gives a negative result for negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-gives-a-negative-result-for-negative-numbers)

Comment: Did you debug? `console.log(n, n % 2, n % 2 === 1, n % 2 !== 0);`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo `%` operator in Javascript divides a number by a divisor (in this case 2), and returns the remainder.

-5 divided by 2 is -2.5, or -2 with a remainder of -1. `2 * -2 + -1 = -5`

5 divided by 2 is 2.5, or 2 with a remainder of 1. `2 * 2 + 1 = 5`

```js
console.log(-5 % 2);
console.log(5 % 2);
```

Comment: This explanation helped a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A negative odd number gives
`n % 2 === -1`.
Just try it out. In the console, type
`-5 % 2`

Comment: This made sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are different possible definitions of the modulus with respect to negative numbers. For some implementations, it's always true that 0 <= |a % b| < |b|; this is tantamount to always using the floor() function to find the integer quotient before computing the remainder. There are many languages with this interpretation, including Common Lisp and Python. You can get a negative value out of the `%` operator in these languages, but only if the *divisor* is negative; the sign of the dividend doesn't change the sign of the result.

In other languages, -|b| < |a % b| < |b|, and the sign of the result *does* depend on the sign of the dividend. This is equivalent to obtaining the integer quotient by rounding toward zero before taking the remainder; C is in this category (since C99; previous editions of the spec left it up to the implementation). So is Javascript, which is why -1 % 2 is not 1, but -1.

The first definition is often more useful, but easy to define in terms of the second:

```
const mod = (a,b) => (a % b + b) % b // mod(-1,2) is 1
```