# Modulo not showing right value

Tags: java, modulo

-46 modulo 7 is 3, but I get -4. Why?

```
int sa=-46;
int p=7;
System.out.println(sa);//-46
sa=sa%p;
System.out.println(sa);//-4
```

Edit:

This is how I solved it

(sa) % p + p) % p;

Comment: -46 mod 7 is actually -4

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does java do modulus calculations with negative numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403542/how-does-java-do-modulus-calculations-with-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java definition of % (remainder operator)

> The Java programming language provides operators that perform
>   addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. There's a good
>   chance you'll recognize them by their counterparts in basic
>   mathematics. The only symbol that might look new to you is "%", which
>   divides one operand by another and returns the remainder as its
>   result.

(see source of reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html))

If you want to create a modulo function that returns only numbers in the range [0, n) when you ask for modulo n you will have to write it (simple).