# Encrypting with large numbers, using a Caesar Cipher

Tags: java, encryption

Right now I have the following code for a Caesar Cipher, but I run into an issue when I try encrypting text with a very large number. 
For example 1000.

```
static String encrypt(String plaintext) {
    StringBuilder ciphertext = new StringBuilder(plaintext);
    for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++) {
        ciphertext.setCharAt(i, encrypt(ciphertext.charAt(i)));
    }
    return ciphertext.toString();
}

static String decrypt(String plaintext) {
    StringBuilder ciphertext = new StringBuilder(plaintext);
    for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++) {
        ciphertext.setCharAt(i, decrypt(ciphertext.charAt(i)));
    }
    return ciphertext.toString();
}

static char encrypt(char c) {
    return (char) ('!' + (c - '!' + 1000) % ('~' - '!' + 1));
}

static char decrypt(char c) {
    return (char) ('!' + (c - '!' - 1000) % ('~' - '!' + 1));
}
```

Lets say I input "abc123" into the encryption, using 1000 as my key, I get a bunch of unknown characters. Keep in mind I don't want it to just cycle through a-z but symbols too, using ASCII codes.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Link to ASCII Table I'm using: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Since you only want to map on the visible ascii characters, 126-33+1=94 possible values. Any key above 93 will have a corresponding smaller key that will do the same thing. 95 will encrypt the same as 1, 0 as 94 etc so a large value like 1000 is unnecessary.

Comment: @rpattiso Even if I use 93 in place of 1000 I still get unknown characters, or nonvisible characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the result of modulo is the same sign as the dividend. So when you compute `c - '!' - 1000` you will get a negative value and after the modulo it will still be negative. When you add '!', you will have computed a values less than '!', which will be invisible or underflow for a char.

```
static char decrypt(char c) {
    char d = '~' - '!' + 1;
    int x = (c - '!' - 1000) % d;
    if (x < 0) x += d;
    return (char)('!' + x);
}
```

Here is a discussion for the problem your running into.

[How does java do modulus calculations with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403542/how-does-java-do-modulus-calculations-with-negative-numbers)

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way x needs to be an int and the return statement needs to be casted to a char. But it works great, thanks again!

Comment: Good catch, please hit the check to close the question.