# How can I increment and decrement an integer with the modulo operator

Tags: java, increment, modulo, decrement

I am trying to increment an integer based on a click. How the click happens does not matter so I'll stick to the logic. I am doing this in Java but the logic should be the same all around.

```
int index = 0;

// then within the click event
//arrySize holds the size() of an ArrayList which is 10

index = (index + 1) % arrySize;
```

With this logic, every time the user clicks, `index` will increment by 1. Then its modulo of `arrySize` causes `index` to go back to 0 when `index` matches `arrySize`

*(10 % 10 would make the index go back to 0)* Which is great because it's kind of like a loop that goes from 0 to 10 then back to 0 and never over 10.

I am trying to do the same logic but **backwards**
where based on the click the number will decrement and get to 0 then
goes back to the `arrySize` instead of `-1`

How can I achieve this logic?

Comment: Yeah I know I can do this with a simple if statement, but was wondering if possible with modulo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(index + arraySize - 1) % arraySize
```

Does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Java 8, you can use the [`Math.floorMod(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-) method. Quoting its Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> The floor modulus is `x - (floorDiv(x, y) * y)`, **has the same sign as the divisor `y`**, and is in the range of `-abs(y) < r < +abs(y)`.

```
System.out.println(Math.floorMod(-1, 5)); // prints 4
```

So you will have:

```
index = Math.floorMod(index - 1, arrySize);
```

You can't have directly `-1 % 5` because that will output `-1` [based on how the operator `%` operates with negatives numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4403542/1743880).

Comment: I see ok this looks good, im going to experiment with this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

index = arraySize - ((index + 1) % arrySize)

Comment: That doesn't quite work. That'll simply move you to the opposite side of the range from 0 to arraySize, then go down by 1. So, while it does work when index = 0, and it also happens to work when index = arraySize/2 (when arraySize is even), it doesn't work for any other values.

I think the correct way of doing this with the % operator is just with (index+arraySize-1)%arraySize. And, in general, floor modding Math.floorMod(a,b) can be done with (a%b+b)%b, or with the probably less expensive 2 lines of code c = a%b; if(c<0) { c+=b; }.

Also you misspelled arraySize the second time

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want 1-based indexing. For example if you wanted to step backwards through months where 1 is January.

```
int previous = ((index - 1 - arraySize) % arraySize) + arraySize
```

Results

```
index    previous
1        12
2        1
3        2
4        3
5        4
6        5
7        6
8        7
9        8
10        9
11        10
12        11
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LuUACE)