# Day of the week using Zeller's method & Java

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek

I am having difficulty getting the correct output of my Zeller's method code, which is suppose to output the day of the week for a given date.

After `int f` is declared, I am not sure how to fix the `if` statement for if a number is less than zero. Here is a chunk of my code:

```
if (month == 1 || month == 2) 
{
    month += 12;
    year--;
} else {
    month-=2;
}

scan.close();        

int m = month;
int d = year % 100; 
int c = (year / 100); 
int k = day;         
int f = (k + (int)((13 * m - 1) / 5.0) + d + (int)(d / 4.0) + (int)(c / 4.0) + (2 * c));        

if (f<=0) 
{
    f= f % 7;
    else
}  

/*   
if (f>0)
{   
    //?
}   
*/

String last = ("Day of the week: ");
System.out.println(f);
```

Comment: "less than zero" ? Your `if` condition without code is handling `if (f >= 0)`. For me, that's a contradiction of your statement. It also doesn't make sense to handle the case `f=0` in both `if` branches and using an `else` would also be nice

Comment: Which nevertheless handles `bigger than zero" ...or not?

Comment: Now it doesn't compile anymore ...

Comment: Anyways, what is the problem with your code now? The Zeller's Congruence is a simple formula which you have implemented by computing `f`, or not?

Comment: Are you sure that the computation is correct? Why `13 * m - 1`? Wikipedia says `13(m+1)` And why do you ignore the math operations ceil in the formula? And it's `+ 5J`. Did you use a different formula? I'm talking about this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence

Comment: The equation I was told to use has 13*m-1 . Also, I am trying to use those but do not know where they should go, or how to implement them properly. I am using this one http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.calendar.html

Comment: my main issue is that if the result of f is negative, it will print the wrong date.

Comment: Ok, I see. The Wikipedia formula solves exactly this issue by using some different terms. Thus, it's always positive.

Comment: I'm just citing the like you showed: *"Suppose f = -17. When we divide by 7, we have to follow the same rules as for the greatest integer function; namely we find the greatest multiple of 7 less than -17, so the remainder will be positive (or zero). -21 is the greatest multiple of 7 less than -17, so the remainder is 4 since -21 + 4 = -17. Alternatively, we can say that -7 goes into -17 twice, making -14 and leaving a remainder of -3, then add 7 since the remainder is negative, so -3 + 7 is again a remainder of 4."*

Comment: What is not clear here? You could use a `while` loop that multiplies a new integer number `int val = -1` by 7 until it's smaller than `f`. Then compute the difference which is the week day

Comment: Look at your `if (f<=0) ` and fix that random **else** text...

Comment: Have you found a solution now? And again, you if is wrong. You want to handle the case when `f` is negative, i.e. `f < 0` Afterwards, you can divide by 7, but not in the if branch

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the formula as stated in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence#Formula). There are some details that differ from your code:

- Month values are `3 = March, 4 = April, 5 = May, ..., 14 = February`. So, your `else { month-=2; }` is not needed: only January and February must be adjusted to be 13 and 14, all the other months must remain unchanged.
- I changed the variables names to match wikipedia's formula:

  - h is the day of the week (`0 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ..., 6 = Friday`)
  - q is the day of the month
  - m is the month (`3 = March, 4 = April, 5 = May, ..., 14 = February`)
  - K the year of the century
  - J is the zero-based century

Another detail (also [explained in the same article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence#Implementation_in_software)), is that the modulo implementation may vary for negative numbers:

> ... −2 mod 7 is equal to positive 5. Unfortunately, the way most computer languages implement the remainder function, −2 mod 7 returns a result of −2.

In Java (I'm using JDK 1.8.0_144), this also happens (`-2 % 7` is equals to `-2`), and one way to fix is to just [add 7 to the final result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403542/how-does-java-do-modulus-calculations-with-negative-numbers). So the code will be like this:

```
// adjust January to 13 and February to 14
if (month == 1 || month == 2) {
    month += 12;
    year--;
}

int j = year / 100;
int k = year % 100;
int q = day;

// using temporary variables to make code cleaner (IMO)
int tmp1 = (13 * (month + 1)) / 5;
int tmp2 = k / 4;
int tmp3 = j / 4;
int h = (q + tmp1 + k + tmp2 + tmp3 - (2 * j)) % 7;
// if result is negative, fix
if (h < 0) {
    h += 7;
}
```

So, `h` will be `0` for Saturday, `1` for Sunday and so on. I've tested with dates from years 1900 to 2100 and it worked fine.

In wikipedia's article, there's also an alternative formula to avoid negative results: just change `- 2J` for `+ 5J`:

```
// change "- (2 * j)" to "+ (5 * j)"
int h = (q + tmp1 + k + tmp2 + tmp3 + (5 * j)) % 7;
```

This will get the same results, but `h` will always be positive (so the `if (h < 0)` is not needed).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

If you're making this code for learning purposes, then it's fine. But for business applications, it's better to use proper date/time API's.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java 6 or 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

An easy way to get the day of the week from a specific date is to use the `LocalDate` class, and then get the `DayOfWeek` from it:

```
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = dt.getDayOfWeek();
// getValue() returns values from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)
int value = dayOfWeek.getValue();
```

The only difference is that the `getValue()` method returns values according to ISO definition, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday). If you need the same values returned by the Zeller's method, though, you can do:

```
int zellerValue = (dayOfWeek.getValue() + 1) % 7;
```